# Seeking global list of registered businesses

Tags: data-request, business

Is there a list somewhere of all registered businesses (both big and small globally) which is free?

I have a list of orders from a list of companies with addresses and i wish to attempt to match the company using text matching. The end result would be: "is the company in my list of reference companies" then set a flag as 1 else set the flag as 0.

Comment: I doubt you are going to find a global dataset. In the US, many states of this for registered companies. But, the address of the registered agent, corporate headquarters, mailing address, and delivery address can all be different.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Probably the closest thing you'll find to this is [OpenCorporates](https://opencorporates.com/). They claim to have data on over 60,000,000 companies.

They don't have a download, but there is an API. It has a [mixed usage license](http://api.opencorporates.com/) depending on whether you are contributing open data back to the community.

Comment: Perfect...I can use this without signing up and have got it working with R....thanks all