# Is there a free open database of all companies/businesses in the world?

Tags: data-request, business, opencorporates

Is there a free open database of all companies/businesses in the world? If not, how would you go about building one, what would you need to do?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Seeking global list of registered businesses](https://opendata.stackexchange.com/questions/4540/seeking-global-list-of-registered-businesses)

Comment: Not really, as far as I can tell the data there is not free.

Comment: Your approach would likely start at supporting the major countries. Australia, US (state-wise...), etc, and for all the work required it'd likely require remuneration to sell-on or make worth it. I once did a project for a specific state to capture business registrations, and I ended up having to learn how to parse old COBOL data formats, so the project would be scattered as far as resources would go. Write a generalized data capture library. Just some ideas.

Comment: No, there isn't. Still, I think you should specify what data you need on those companies, as the question is a vague. Some data is available, but you need to clarify

Answer (score 2):

You can scrape the following [Wikipedia-pages](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Category:Lists_of_companies_by_country) and use the [opencorporate-API](https://api.opencorporates.com/) to build your own/ custom database.
Otherwise, here are some limited but yet useful resources/ datasets:

- https://www.opendata500.com/us/list/
- [reddit/the_largest_open_database_of_companies_in_the_world/](https://www.reddit.com/r/InternetIsBeautiful/comments/2tzgy0/the_largest_open_database_of_companies_in_the/)
- https://www.opensecrets.org/industries/alphalist.php